# Change the colors of the Sphinx Read The Docs theme?

Tags: css, colors, python-sphinx, read-the-docs, dark-theme

I'm building documentation for my API library and I'm having readthedocs.io host the documentation, and is backed with Sphinx. I have the Read The Docs theme installed for Sphinx using `pip install`, and the Read the Docs website currently has the documentation running.

I would like to change the colors of my documentation. I have done some searching through their GitHub repository [GitHub.com](https://github.com/rtfd/sphinx_rtd_theme) and have seen some talk that editing the `sass` files. However, I can't seem to find where these files are located.

[image: Example of a Read The Docs with other colors]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I believe the canonical way is to create a `_static` folder, include CSS files in that, and then reference that CSS in your templates with an include in the `_templates` folder.

To demonstrate this, you can try a simple override of the `layout.html` file: first, create `_templates` in your docs folder if it doesn't already exist, then create a file there named `layout.html`.

Populate that with the following:

```
{% extends "!layout.html" %}
  {% block footer %} {{ super() }}

  <style>
    /* Sidebar header (and topbar for mobile) */
    .wy-side-nav-search, .wy-nav-top {
      background: #00ff00;
    }
    /* Sidebar */
    .wy-nav-side {
      background: #ff0000;
    }
  </style>
{% endblock %}
```

Once you've rebuilt your docs, you should see a garish side-bar and header. (I used a similar technique with our Sphinx / Read The Docs theme [implementation](https://docs.reincubate.com/ricloud/). View source etc. to see which bits we override.)

Comment: If you just want to change the simplest colors of the theme, this answer works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: If it wasn't clear (i.e. if you're a noob like me) you can replace the `<style>` block with `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_static/custom.css">` and put the CSS code in `_static/custom.css` as long as your `conf.py` contains `html_static_path = ['_static']`.

Answer (score 13):

You can change the theme colors by adding a custom CSS file to `_static`. To actually have Sphinx use that file, add this to your `conf.py`:

```py
def setup(app):
    app.add_css_file('custom.css')
```

Sample CSS (`custom.css`) to change the sidebar color to dark-green (based on @afit's answer):

```css
.wy-side-nav-search, .wy-nav-top {
    background: #0b750a;
}
```

Comment: didn't work for me

Comment: @GonzaloGarcia: you may need to run `make clean`, `make html`. The sample CSS was useful for me. However, i replaced the `def setup(app)...` part by Azmisovs answer.

Comment: @GonzaloGarcia What Sphinx version are you on? I just checked again using Sphinx 5.2.2 and it still works fine for me. The `html_css_files` approach also works fine by the way.

Answer (score 8):

If you only want to change the color of the navigation header, you can do that by using the `html_theme_options` variable in `conf.py`. There is parameter called `'style_nav_header_background'`.

https://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuring.html#theme-options

Comment: getting `preparing documents... WARNING: unsupported theme option 'style_nav_header_background' given`

Comment: @GonzaloGarcia yep, this didn't work for me either.

Comment: @david adding a custom css worked for me. You just have to force using the color you want with `!important;` at the end of each line

Answer (score 7):

An easier way to add CSS files is to set `html_css_files` in your conf.py:

```py
# custom.css is inside one of the html_static_path folders (e.g. _static)
html_css_files = ["custom.css"]
```

See: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/adding-custom-css.html